# Js with ajax couse error on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, web, telerik

I have a JS script to popup a calendar.If i put AJAX on the page to avoid refresh i got error :

**The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).**

I have read that if i change <%= to <%# should work. I try it and the page loads but the function does not work.

js

```
   function ShowDatePopup() {

               $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>").showPopup();
           }
```

aspx

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1"  Runat="server" Culture="el-GR" Visible="False" Skin="WebBlue" AutoPostBack="True"  >
<Calendar runat="server"  UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False"  UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" EnableWeekends="True" FastNavigationNextText="&amp;lt;&amp;lt;" Skin="WebBlue"></Calendar>
<DateInput runat="server"  DisplayDateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" DateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" LabelWidth="40%" EmptyMessage="Ex: 2015/01/24" AutoPostBack="True"  >
      <ClientEvents    OnFocus="ShowDatePopup"/>
<EmptyMessageStyle Resize="None"></EmptyMessageStyle>

<ReadOnlyStyle Resize="None"></ReadOnlyStyle>

<FocusedStyle Resize="None"></FocusedStyle>

<DisabledStyle Resize="None"></DisabledStyle>

<InvalidStyle Resize="None"></InvalidStyle>

<HoveredStyle Resize="None"></HoveredStyle>

<EnabledStyle Resize="None"></EnabledStyle>

   </DateInput>
<DatePopupButton  ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>  
   </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

What i am doing wrong and how i can fix this?

Comment: try $("<%= #RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>").showPopup();

Comment: I get this error: Preprocessor directives must apprear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

Comment: srry made a error there ..try $("#<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>").showPopup();

Comment: Is not working.The same error like my code on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the Visible property to true to actually get the control (and, by extension, its client-side object) on the page in the browser
2. Wrap your server code blocks in RadCodeBlock tags: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-radscriptblock-radcodeblock.html.

Here is your snippet working fine for me:

```
        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server" Culture="el-GR" Visible="true" Skin="WebBlue" AutoPostBack="True">
            <Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" EnableWeekends="True" FastNavigationNextText="&amp;lt;&amp;lt;" Skin="WebBlue"></Calendar>
            <DateInput ID="DateInput1" runat="server" DisplayDateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" DateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" LabelWidth="40%" EmptyMessage="Ex: 2015/01/24" AutoPostBack="True">
                <ClientEvents OnFocus="ShowDatePopup" />
                <EmptyMessageStyle Resize="None"></EmptyMessageStyle>
                <ReadOnlyStyle Resize="None"></ReadOnlyStyle>
                <FocusedStyle Resize="None"></FocusedStyle>
                <DisabledStyle Resize="None"></DisabledStyle>
                <InvalidStyle Resize="None"></InvalidStyle>
                <HoveredStyle Resize="None"></HoveredStyle>
                <EnabledStyle Resize="None"></EnabledStyle>
            </DateInput>
            <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
        <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
            <script>
                function ShowDatePopup() {
                    $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>").showPopup();
                }
            </script>
        </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: I set Visible property to False because i change it to True from the code when I need it

Comment: sorry about that, but I had to note the fact :)